# Typescript: How to set value to empty string

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, reduce, setvalue

I'm doing sorting and grouping the data based on first word that split with `_` (underscore). So result should return 3 groups (eg: `orders, items and ""`). How I can set some value (eg: Others) to that empty string. Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-p5ujfm?embed=1&file=index.ts)

```
let rawData = [
  { name : 'orders_list', id : 10},
  { name : 'orders_price', id : 7},
  { name : 'items_list', id : 12 },
  { name : 'items_price', id : 7},
  { name : 'others-list', id : 7},
  { name : 'secondOthers-list', id : 7},
]

let data = rawData.reduce((r, e) => {

  let group = e.name.substr(0, e.name.indexOf('_'));

  if(!r[group]) {
    r[group] = {group, children: [e]}
  } else {
    r[group].children.push(e);
  }

  return r;
}, {})

let result = Object.values(data)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: your stackblitz is working fine

Comment: Yes correct but third item in array returning empty string. How I can replace empty string with "Others" value ?

Comment: write a unit test with your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working stackblitz I made :)

```
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';

// Write TypeScript code!
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>TypeScript Starter</h1>`;

let rawData = [
  { name : 'orders_list', id : 10},
  { name : 'orders_price', id : 7},
  { name : 'items_list', id : 12 },
  { name : 'items_price', id : 7},
  { name : 'others-list', id : 7},
  { name : 'secondOthers-list', id : 7},
]


let data = rawData.reduce((r, e) => {

  let group = e.name.substr(0, e.name.indexOf('_'));

  if(!r[group]) {
    r[group] = {group, children: [e]}
  } else {
    r[group].children.push(e);
  }

  return r;
}, {})

// since data at this point is an object, to get array of values
// we use Object.values method
let result = Object.values(data)
var resultMap = result.map(_val => {
  return _val.group
})
var index = resultMap.indexOf('')
result[index].group = 'Others'

console.log(result)
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-6xfk3j

Answer (score -1):

Check this.

```
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';

// Write TypeScript code!
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>TypeScript Starter</h1>`;

let rawData = [
  { name : 'orders_list', id : 10},
  { name : 'orders_price', id : 7},
  { name : 'items_list', id : 12 },
  { name : 'items_price', id : 7},
  { name : 'others-list', id : 7},
  { name : 'secondOthers-list', id : 7},
]


let data = rawData.reduce((r, e) => {

  let group = e.name.substr(0, e.name.indexOf('_'));

  if(!r[group]) {
    r[group] = {group, children: [e]}
  } else {
    r[group].children.push(e);
  }

  return r;
}, {})

// since data at this point is an object, to get array of values
// we use Object.values method
let result = Object.values(data)
result.filter(f=>{
  if(f.group==''){
    f.group='Others'
  }
});

console.log(result)
```

StackBlitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pe8k9p